# Can't install `yt-core` gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, yt

Thank you for reading this question.

```
$ gem install yt
Successfully installed yt-0.32.4
1 gem installed
$ gem which yt
/Users/klee/.rbenv/versions/2.5.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/yt-0.32.4/lib/yt.rb
$ gem install yt-core
Successfully installed yt-core-0.1.7
1 gem installed
$ gem which yt-core
ERROR:  Can't find Ruby library file or shared library yt-core
```

I keep trying to install this gem, but it keeps saying "Can't find." Same thing happens to you? How can I install and find this gem? This is the gem I'm trying to install https://rubygems.org/gems/yt-core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-which):

> **GEM WHICH**
>
> Find the location of a library file you can require

So when you call `gem which` you need to provide an actual module you can require, not just the name of the gem. And if you look at [the source](https://github.com/Fullscreen/yt/blob/master/lib/yt.rb) for the yt gem you'll see the following structure:

```
lib/
  yt.rb
```

And you'll notice that the content of `yt.rb` is:

```
module Yt
end
```

So when you call `gem which yt` it is able to find that module and tell you where to find it. (`lib/yt.rb`)

But if you look at [the source for yt-core](https://github.com/Fullscreen/yt-core/tree/master/lib) you'll see there is no file inside the `lib/` directory, and instead all files are inside `lib/yt`:

```
lib/
  yt/
    ...
    core.rb
    ...
```

And [the source for `core.rb`](https://github.com/Fullscreen/yt-core/blob/master/lib/yt/core.rb) is:

```
module Yt
end
```

So if you want to find the location of the module, you need to run:

```
gem which yt/core
/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/yt-core-0.1.7/lib/yt/core.rb
```

Or `yt/channel` or `yt/group`, etc.

So to use this gem, you would need to include this in your source:

```
require 'yt/core'
```